# How long do Ziehl-Neelsen stained samples keep?

Tags: microscopy

I have acquired TB slides from my city's health center that are supposedly acid-fast bacteria (AFB) positive. However, when I took a look at it, I see basically no carbol fuchsin stains.

They were individually neatly folded in paper. When I opened them, the stains were slightly wet with immersion oil, facing down. [So far, so good (page 6).](http://whocctblab.fondazionesanraffaele.it/uploads/2/0/8/2/20828554/ios_ebp_dma_001_ziehl-neelsen_staining_rev_1.pdf) I've been later informed that these samples were prepared **Q1 2019**. Based on my research, the staining solutions themselves last up to 12 months ([page 33](http://www.stoptb.org/wg/gli/assets/documents/tb%20microscopy%20handbook_final.pdf)). I can't find any data on how long a stained sample would keep though.

Do they decolorize over time? I expected the AFB to be bright, or at least slightly pink, but I see no such thing. I do see bacilli, though all of them are nearly transparent/methylene blue in color.

---

Here are some sample images. The first 2 are how I expected AFB to look like, while the next 2 are what I captured (and I think should contain AFB). The last pic is a 10um/div calibration slide for reference.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This TB study might help you: [external page](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5952665/)

Briefly, they used 6 to 19 months old samples of mostly bad quality (due to their age). The last sentence of the quote below sounds promising though.

> The 12,543 sputum smears stored at the national TB reference
> laboratory for 6 to 19 months were stored at room temperature in a
> wooden slide box without a cover slip. Most of them had lost their
> stain reflecting the counterstaining with methylene blue. Restaining
> of 436 doubtful slides by ZN gave disappointing results throughout [...]
>
> After a 6 to 19 months storage of ZN stained sputum smears in a
> non-air conditioned atmosphere, the bright red color of eggs due to
> carbolfuchsin had virtually disappeared. [...] In such case, the ZN restaining of sputum smears allows to rediscover AFB that were discolored.

When I did this the last time, we used fresh and few months old samples which looked similar to the first of your images. Just have a look at the paper, I guess.